# Can I get the photoplethysmography(PPG) data from apple watch?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I want to get the PPG data from apple watch. However I don't know whether Apple support this function or not.
I know I can get the raw data of Heart Rate(HR) from watch after watch OS 2, but what I need is not heart rate data but PPG data such as below link

http://www.intechopen.com/source/html/16117/media/image27.png